# Free memory debugger for Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

I am looking for a free memory debugger for Windows, suited for debugging C++ applications built with VC, with similiar functionality to Insure++ or Purify.

Any recomendations?

- GUI is a plus
- Integration with VS is a bigger plus

Answer (score 2):

[Ollydbg](http://ollydbg.de/) is also pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

valgrind + cygwin

ANSIMD (Ansi Memory Debugger)

UPS Debugger

GoBug Debugger

Microsoft Debugging Tools

Stack Trace Analysis Tool (STAT)

Mono Migration Analysis

http://www.debuginfo.com/ - Might be some of tools u can find over there

Answer (score 1):

Try [DUMA](http://duma.sourceforge.net/), I have used it before, it's cross-platform and the latest release is recent.

Answer (score 0):

Purify is a memory profiler. 
You can try DebugDiag provided by windows.It can give you memory dumps and at various points and you can then check for memory leaks.

Windbg is also good.